# The spatial thinking course for primary school - what to use?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, primary-education, mathematics-in-daily-life, critical-thinking

We're planning to run the project for first two grades of the elementary school kids, in which we want to facilitate the spatial thinking development along with the regular arithmetic course and make it easier for them to get into advanced math in further educational levels. What would you recommend to start with and which well-recognized and trusted textbooks, approaches, methodologies, and quizzes do you know what may ease this task?

We're located in Moscow as a company, but going to work way beyond the region, besides, anyway, I wanted to make sure it's possible in general for the considerably early age (6-9 y.o.) from the psychological point of view, first of all, without binding to the local realia of the region.

There are two disputable articles I've read up to the moment in this direction:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313588375_The_Development_of_Spatial_Skills_in_Elementary_School_Students
http://ling.umd.edu/~jlidz/Teaching/F05Seminar/feigensondehaenespelke04.pdf

Also, I checked the OECD report about the early STEM preparation and correlation with spatial thinking and math skills development:
https://www.oecd.org/officialdocuments/publicdisplaydocumentpdf/?cote=EDU/WKP(2017)10&docLanguage=En

Thank you for help :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "get into advanced math?" By advanced math, do you mean algebra?

Comment: Additionally, giving us information about your location would help, since education norms are different in different places. Your profile indicates you are in Moscow; is this for elementary students in Moscow?

Comment: What age are the kids? Age 5 is a lot different from age 11. What does "first two classes" mean? First two classes of the day? Is there evidence that spatial thinking is trainable? That it's necessary? Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Under class I meant "grade", sorry :-) Age period is between 6 and 9.

Comment: Yes, the organization is placed in Moscow itself, but we're planning to go beyond the region. The planning programs are not online and suggest the face-to-face tutoring over a big group of kids (30, 40 in the room).

Comment: You might check this out: http://www.inference.org.uk/sanjoy/benezet/    In the 1920's, school superintendent Benezet experimented with doing no conventional math instruction for the early grades, because the kids turn to memorizing. But they did lots of measurement. Anything that doesn't use an algorithm might be good for independent thinking. For spatial thinking, get them all playing with blocks. Kapla/Keva/Citi blocks are good for large projects.

Comment: @SueVanHattum but Benezet, as I know, was experimenting with shifting the math course up to the 6th grade. I know about this experiment and (if I don't confuse anything) that there are not so many evidence, except 1935, when one of the teachers was trying to adopt these techniques for her masters degree. If you know about any materials for the primary school from his side - I'd be appreciated, if you share them with me, I'll check them out.

Comment: In my experience, building Lego objects develops spatial thinking.

Comment: What does "without binding to the local realia of the region" mean?

Comment: @BenCrowell I mean without local specifics like educational standarts and reforms, first of all I'd like to make sure it works on primary level of education in general.

Comment: @paus I don't know anything more about it. Just that they emphasized measurement in the early grades.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you, anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not a systematic course proposal, but a list of useful references I've collected about the subject:

- A must read for your staff team (it brings arguments from neuroscience): [Mind in Motion: How Action Shapes Thought](https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/B07KW5F7R9/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1) by Barbara Tversky.
- [Perspective Taking: building a neurocognitive framework for integrating the “social” and the “spatial”](https://www.frontiersin.org/research-topics/1167/perspective-taking-building-a-neurocognitive-framework-for-integrating-the-social-and-the-spatial) by Kessler et al.
- [The Relationship between Language and Spatial Ability: An Analysis of Spatial Language for Reconstructing the Solving of Spatial Tasks](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783658206314) by Mizzi Angel.
- [Visual-spatial Ability in STEM Education: Transforming Research into Practice](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319443843) by Myint Swe Khine.
- [Spatial Reasoning in the Early Years: Principles, Assertions, and Speculations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138792039) by Brent David and The Spatial Reasoning Study Group.
- [Spatial Ability for STEM Domains: Aligning Over 50 Years of Cumulative Psychological Knowledge Solidifies Its Importance](https://my.vanderbilt.edu/smpy/files/2013/02/Wai2009SpatialAbility.pdf) by Jonathan Wai, David Lubinski, and Camilla P. Benbow.
- [The  Decline  and  Rise  of  Geometry  in  20th  Century](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~whiteley/cmesg.pdf) by Walter Whiteley.
- [Jenga Views](https://twitter.com/davidkbutleruoa/status/1001662373348818945) by David Butler. File is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rPl5rv1C6QgpSEtEKHkFjKIbpYHmhhO7/view).
- [Twelve Exercises On Spatial Perception](https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2099/1045/st14-09-a6-ocr.pdf) by Janos Baracs.
- While concrete manipulatives are highly recommended for early ages (see the Jenga Views activity, 3D printer projects and [Perplexus 3D Maze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexus)), I would like to suggest the use of a 3D dynamic geometry software like GeoGebra 3D (https://www.geogebra.org/download). In particular, there is a module for augmented reality using GeoGebra for smartphones that allows unique experiences. Please, see the videos: https://youtu.be/l2B-RS6xrvg, https://youtu.be/_rnzLbF_WKo, https://youtu.be/e_HoHZPSdTQ, https://youtu.be/QC7Yg6-D2lA, https://youtu.be/YjT7dQsuZg8. Moreover, it would be a great exercise if your students use the software to buid by themselves their own AR constructions in GeoGebra 3D.

[image]

- This is a 3D game that connects Spatial Thinking with Languages: [Trip-Lets](http://www.cdme.im-uff.mat.br/html5/triplets/triplets-html/triplets-en.html). Here a children playing with it: https://youtu.be/n5ymEpqvfSQ. The game also appeared in the "Geometry and Imagination" at ICM 2018 at Rio de Janeiro. There are version in English, French, German, Spanish and Portuguese. If you want, we may try to provide a version in Russian.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you :-) What about trusted methodologies as a package for 1-2 grades of school? Are there any on the market teachers may use and measure the quality?